# Sslhandshake Java 6 and tls 1.2

Tags: java, fuse, web-services

When client application running with oracle Jdk 6 tries to invoke my application which is running on Jdk 7 it gets error stating remote host closed during connection sslhandshake exception. The same works fine with Java 7

The client application can't upgrade themselves due to product restrictions

Can anyone tell me how to fix it